# Find all Mongo document with array containing all search terms

Tags: mongodb

I have set of documents that contain an array of search terms, e.g.

```
[ "apples", "oranges", "bananas" ]
```

The user will enter a search string of keyword prefixes, and I'd like to match all the documents that contain each term in the array. So, for example, "app oranges" will match the list above, but "applet oranges" wouldn't.

It would be fairly trivial to construct a $and query that checked that each term matched one of the items in the array as a prefix using $regex, however that doesn't go far enough...

Each keyword should have a unique match within the set, such that searching "apples app" will not match the list above because the "app" term can't match against "apple" since "apple" has already been matched. This constraint leads to a more subtle problem. Take this set as an example:

```
[ "france", "fred", "freddy" ]
```

If the user taps "fr france" then this should match. It's important that the match for "fr" doesn't remove "france" from the possible list of terms for the remaining keywords, otherwise the test for the term "france" that follows would fail.

I need to implement this as a Mongo query. I'm quite new to Mongo and I have't a clue where to start, or even of this is possible. Can it be done? If so, how?

Comment: If you can live with the fact that multiple matches can occur: How about a [text index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/) on the array? You could sort the results by the score they are achieving, have automatic stemming and alike. Of course, it will be a bit fuzzy. Since you didn't describe your use case, it is hard to judge wether text indexing fits your needs.

Answer (score 1):

To start with, you can use the [$regex](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) operator to match text patterns:

```
var searchTerms = "app oranges".split(" ");
var arr = [];
searchTerms.forEach(function(i){
var reg = new RegExp("^"+i);
arr.push({"names":{$regex:reg}});
})
db.collection.find({$and:arr});
```

Would give you the documents with array `names` containing values starting with `app` and containing `oranges`.

> *Each keyword should have a unique match within the set, such that searching "apples app" will not match the list above because the "app"
>   term can't match against "apple" since "apple" has already been
>   matched. This constraint leads to a more subtle problem. Take this set
>   as an example:*

This logic should be carried out in the application server before/after firing the query. If the user enters a string that is a `substring` of another **former** input, then the query is bound to fail since it would have already matched the fromer.

Comment: That's doesn't solve the heart of the issue. I've updated my question to make that clearer.

Comment: No. If the user enters "app apples" then that should match an array like ["apples", "application"], but it shouldn't match ["apples", "orange"]

Comment: `apples` is not a prefix for `apple`. So the first case wouldn't match.

Comment: That was just a typo. Fixed.

Comment: Your answer would construct { $and: [ {"names": { $regEx: "^apples" }}, {"names": { $regEx: "^app" }} ]. That *would* match [ "apples", "oranges" ] since both regEx expression match against "apples".

Comment: `If the user taps "fr france" then this should match. It's important that the match for "fr" doesn't remove "france"` - why are your comments contradicting your question?

Comment: What I'm was trying to say was that if you were to construct an algorithm that removed a search term from consideration as soon as it's matched, it would potentially cause a valid search to fail. i.e. if you first match "fr" against "france" and then stop comparing the other terms to "france" (so that each search term matches a unique term in the array), then the remaining search term "france" would have nothing left to match against and the search would fail. In this case you need to *first* match "france", then match "fr" against "fred".